# R Geospatial Aggregation: Collapsing Directionality without Using Forloop (Remove Duplicates)

Tags: r, combinations, aggregation

I am trying to perform aggregation (basic sum) on geospatial data that contains directionality information. I am trying to collapse the directionality dimension. So if A -> B and B -> A, then count both.

I have the following data:

`u <- data.frame(str_statn=c(42, 106, 3, 6, 4), end_statn=c(106, 42, 6, 3, 14), cnt=c(23, 7, 100, 102, 1))`

I need to make it look like this:

`v <- data.frame(str_statn=c(42, 3, 4), end_statn=c(106, 6, 14), cnt=c(30, 202, 1))`

I understand I can use a for loop but I was looking for a more elegant and faster solution. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You''ll probably have to sort by row first and then simply aggregate, here's a possible solution

```
u[1:2] <- t(apply(u, 1, function(x) sort(x[1:2])))
aggregate(cnt ~., u, sum)
#   str_statn end_statn cnt
# 1        42       106  30
# 2         3         6 202
# 3         4        14   1
```